# Put image's caption out of slider

Tags: javascript, css, masterslider

I am facing a big deal which is I would like to place the caption of the image out of the slider. 
I have master slider, and the slider shows images of my projects.
what I would like is to place the name of each project under the slider (out of slider not inside), and the names should be changed relatively with the images.
I tried to fix it but it didn't work.
Here is my code script:
this the html:

```
<div class="master-slider ms-skin-contrast" id="masterslider" >
        {% for project in projects %}
            <div class="ms-slide">
                <img src="{{asset('uploads/images/')}}{{project.images[0].name}}" data-src="{{asset('uploads/images/')}}{{project.images[0].name}}" alt="{{project.name}}"/>
                <div class="ms-layer ms-caption" id="image-caption">
                     {{project.name}}
                </div>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

this is the css

```
#image-caption{
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 9999; /* Stay on top */
    top: 250px;
    right: 800px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now I have some idea how it works. This would be A LOT easier with your full CSS, but you may try something like this just to see what happens:

```
#image-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
}
```

Comment: it worked, but the names are not changing relatively with the slider. they are all displayed

Comment: I think , to be displayed relatively with the image, the script of the project name should be inside ms-slide as I did.

Comment: the placement of the names works , they are outside the slider, but they are not changing, they all are displayed at the same time

Comment: @RóchdíBóuslámá Go back to the original format of the HTML.

Comment: I did it . But the position of the name is inside the slider.